# Limit theorem for integral of quotient of sums

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, limits, solution-verification

I want to show the following limit theorem:

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:[0,1]\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ be integrable functions such that $\lvert f\rvert\le Cg$ for some $C>0$. Then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{[0,1]^n}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^ng(x_i)}dx_1,...,dx_n = \frac{\int_0^1 f(x)dx}{\int_0^1g(x)dx}$$

This is an exercise in my advanced probability course, even though it's a purely analytical result, and I'm stuck on the following step:
It seems clear that the result should be derived somehow using the strong law of large numbers.

(EDIT) This is my most promising attempt so far: for independent, uniformly distributed $X_i$ and using the dominated convergence to theorem to pull the limit in we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{[0,1]^n}\frac{\sum_i^nf(x_i)}{\sum_i^ng(x_i)}dx_1,...,dx_n 
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\left(\frac{\sum_i^nf(X_i)}{\sum_i^ng(X_i)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_j^nE\left(\frac{f(X_j)}{\sum_i^ng(X_i)}\right) \\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\left(\frac{nf(X_1)}{\sum_i^ng(X_i)}\right)  \\
&=E\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(X_1)}{n^{-1}\sum_i^ng(X_i)}\right)\\
&=E\left(\frac{f(X_1)}{E(g(X_1))}\right)\\
&=\frac{E(f(X_1))}{E(g(X_1))} = \frac{\int_0^1f(x)dx}{\int_0^1g(x)dx}
\end{aligned}$$

Is the "transformation" from the n-dimensional integral to the expected value allowed as I wrote it? Did I make any errors?

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit too late for the party. But I would say I agree with your attempt, the first line is also great. However, the problem occurs in the fourth line. I don't know how you can pass the limit inside the expectation, but if you have used the DCT, then that's not true.

Comment: Optimally, you can apply the DCT right after the second line, as your inner term converges a.s to our desired value. Furthermore, it is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from my post is in fact complete.